# Serial Port Communication

Tags: visual-c++, serial-port, mscomm32

I want to send data hex format (0x01) or (0xff) to the port where rs232 cable is connected. I am using the MSCOMM control in VC++ 6.0. Is that the correct way to send the hex data. This is the code I have.

```
CString output;
UCHAR data1,data2;
data1=0x01;
output.Format("%x",data1);
m_mscom.SetOutput(COleVariant(output));
data2=0xff;
output.Format("%x",data2);
m_mscom.SetOutput(COleVariant(output));
```

If it is not correct, please tell me how to send hex format data to the port.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If your data is simply a hex value that you want to send out (as opposed to a hex formatted string), you probably want "%c" rather than "%x".  Given a data value of (e.g.) 0x65, "%x" will produce two bytes on the serial port: '6' (ascii value 54) and '5' (ascii value 53).  "%c" will produce a single byte on the serial port: 'e' (ascii value 100 or 0x65).

As far as sending data on a serial port in C, have a look at [CSerial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/serialcommunications/article.php/c2503) or [CSerialPort](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/I-N/network/serialcommunications/article.php/c2483): they may simplify things for you a bit (note that I've not used them, I tend to do serial port apps in python with the [pyserial](http://pyserial.wiki.sourceforge.net/pySerial) module or in [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) with the [ctb](https://iftools.com/opensource/ctb.en.php) library).

Edit: The other one that's quite good (I have used it before, but couldn't find the link when I wrote the original post) is [CSerialFile](http://www.samblackburn.com/wfc/Serial.htm), part of the [WFC](http://www.samblackburn.com/wfc) libraries.  As I said, I tend to use wxWidgets now, but if you're using the Microsoft foundation classes, CSerialFile does make serial access very easy.

Comment: what is wxWidgets?How it is useful?

Comment: wxWidgets is a GUI library (primarily for C++) that is free and open source.  I find its design better than the Microsoft Foundation Classes (which seem to be too closely based on the C API rather than designed as a C++ library).  The wxWidgets libraries have the added advantage that the source code will compile without changes for Windows, Linux & Mac, so your application becomes cross-platform for free!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no familiar with MSCOM but it seems like it won't work. `Format` may re-format the data to an ASCII string representation instead.

Alternatively, you can just use any serial port as a 'file' in Windows. Look at the windows api for opening files and you will see that you can address certain devices as files by using a filename like 'COM1:' instead.

Then, you can read/write from it like a file.